# why I need a dynamic query for "column value from a query"

Tags: sql

For example this returns a value from a query, which I will then use as a column name.

```
@A=Select top 1 productid from productlist order by timestamp desc
```

then I would like this "productid" A to be used in the other table

```
Select @A from customerlist
```

then the result is @A value instead of field value in customerlist.

When I use dynamic query, I can get right result.
Why?

(I know I can use join but because this productlist table is dynamic, so let's assume it is a sub query)

Comment: (1) You have a problem with your data model if you have columns that are really data fields.  (2) This requires dynamic SQL, so you need to specify the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need "dynamic SQL" because SQL will NOT allow you to use a parameter as a column name or a table name. You can only use parameters for data values such as in a where clause `where column1 = @val`

```
set @A = 'çolumn1'
Select @A from customerlist -- this fails because it is not allowed
```

Dynamic SQL is a "hack" to get around those restrictions as the SQL statement is placed into a string along with any **value** held by parameters.

```
set @A = 'çolumn1'
set @SQL = 'Select ' + @A + ' from customerlist;'

execute @SQL -- this works, the SQL statement is valid with no parameters as column names
```

The string formed as @SQL is a complete sql statement without needing any parameters as column names.

Note: the syntax I used here is incomplete and is based on MS SQL Server, different databases will use a different, but similar, syntax.